# Code below IF statement is never executed

Tags: debugging, go

There's a section of my code that has unexpected behaviour.

```
. . .
fmt.Println("Error:", err)
if err == nil {
    return err
}
fmt.Println("Done category")
. . .
```

The section above has the following output

```
Error: <nil>
```

The code below if statement is never executed. If I remove the if statement the code behaves as expected.

Reference: https://github.com/skarllot/flogviewer/blob/master/wlog/parser.go#L138

Comment: well `err` is equal to `nil` so the condition in if statement is true and the function returns.

Comment: Are you asking why the if statement is true or why returning from the function stops the rest of the function from being executed? What *is* the expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's step through it.

```
fmt.Println("Error:", err)
```

If the output is `Error: <nil>` .. then your `err` variable is `nil`.

```
if err == nil {
    return err
}
```

This is saying .. "if the `err` variable is `nil` (which it is .. we established that above) ... then return the `nil` value.

At this point .. your function has returned.. so nothing else below it will run.

Perhaps you meant this line instead?:

```
if err != nil {
//     ^^ NOT equal?
```

Comment: I can't believe that I done such a primary error. I struggling so much time with interface{} (I miss generics) that I missed it.